# How do I set the type of 'user' properly in useState [user, setuser], so that I dont get type error when I extract the json data in the return? React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is a beginner question so please don't hate. Please explain as much as you can.

The program is working just fine, but in the typescript console, I am getting this error.

```bash
Property 'bio' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

```js
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Github(){
    const [user , setUser] = useState([]);
    let fetchUserData = () => {
        fetch("https://api.github.com/users/userName")
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            setUser(data)
        })
    }
    useEffect( () => {
        fetchUserData()
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            {typeof(user.bio)}
        </div>
    )

}
```

This has happened when I am trying to extract the property from user. If I use alternative notation to grab the data, i.e, `user['bio']`, typescript does not show any error.

I am trying to understand React, Next JS and Typescript. I tried documentation and other tutorials.

I also tried to declare an interface above useState for user, but nothing worked. Please advice !

Comment: If the correct type for the state can't be inferred from the default value, supply the generic parameter: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to provide a generic type parameter when calling `useState()`:

```
// Declared somewhere, likely another file
interface User {
  bio: string
}

 const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
```

This will result in the value being `User | undefined`, so you'll still need to check the value isn't undefined (or use optional chaining):

```
<div>
  {user?.bio}
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can provide a default value to `useState()`:

```
// outside component
const BLANK_USER: User = { bio: '' }

// inside component
const [user, setUser] = useState(BLANK_USER)
```

Personally, I'd go with providing a type argument, as using a default value like this could get weird -- it will be wrong if your type doesn't specify all properties of a user, for example.

Note: in your example, you've passed an array (`[]`) as a default, which is wrong. You probably meant to pass an empty object `{}`, but TypeScript isn't going to like that.